# How can I open the tab the notification came from?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-notifications

I want to use HTML5 notifications:

```
var n = new Notification("Hello");
```

**How can I open the tab, the notification came from?**

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `onclick` event and call `window.open`.

```
n.onclick = function() { 
    window.open(yourUrl);
};
```

Comment: I want to open the tab which contains the url in an existing tab instead of a new one.

Comment: @confile just use window.location

Comment: ``window.location = url`` reloads the page in an existing tab but does not open the tab.

Comment: How can I open the tab, the notification came from?

Comment: @confile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906976/how-to-get-focus-to-a-chrome-tab-which-created-desktop-notification

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener for the `click` event and then use `window.focus`. For example:

```
var n = new Notification("Hello");

n.addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.focus();
});
```

Comment: I want to open the tab which contains the url in an existing tab instead of a new one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, java script does not know if there are any other tabs open and surely not which websites you currently browse.

With a notification you can only open the tab where the notification came from, which should be the default behavior, if you click the notification.

Comment: How can I open the tab, the notification came from?

Comment: for chrome, `window.focus()` should work. And in my Fire Fox, clicking a notification without any event handlers opens the tab.