# Chrome Notification onClick go to Tab

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, tabs, window, focus

I have a simple chrome extension that sends a notification (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/) from the extension's background script. Upon clicking on the notification, a content script is executed via the chrome.tabs.query function using a url match. Inside the script I've been trying everything to focus the tab it's running on, with no success.

background.js:

```
const focusTab = () => {
  chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'myUrlMatch'}, tabs => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'focustab.js' });
  });
}
// I'm calling focusTab from the chrome.notifications.onClicked listener callback. From the click until inside the below f() function everything works.
```

focustab.js:

```
function f() {
  window.focus();
  window.parent.focus();
  window.parent.parent.focus(); //just to make sure
}

setTimeout(f, 0); //superstition coming from angularJS
```

I cannot believe it's impossible to focus the tab a notification is originating from. I've read conflicting things about the permissions one has when it comes to navigating with windows and tabs in modern browsers. I'm reading a lot about window.focus() but nothing seems to be happening at all when I try playing around with that in chrome.

**This is a fairly logical interaction in my eyes, to expect a notification click to take you to the tab it's coming from.** Just how it works with iOS push notifications.

What am I doing wrong to get something so trivial not to work? I've read that due to security concerns browsers don't allow you to focus/switch a tab etc. I understand this makes sense in the general context of running js code, but in this specific context of clicking a notification, we clearly have a type of user consent and intention here, we even have a specific 'notifications' permission in the extension's manifest file. This must be possible.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you share extension sample

Comment: I updated my question, was able to solve it

Comment: can you share the answer if you have solved it

Comment: I did on the top of my question ;)

Comment: instead of adding it to question please add that as answer.

Comment: I don't see a reason for that since my answer is at the very top of my question, in dark bold letters

Comment: @rails_has_elegance StackOverflow is a QnA site, please remove the answer from your question and add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster, as well as another user, have rightfully come to the following conclusion:

> Pure JS solutions don't have the power to do this for security reasons[, logically]

A good Security StackExchange thread about this can be found [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/198780/why-is-javascript-safe-to-run-in-the-browser). The appendix "*logically*" (OP used that word beautifully in this context) is very fitting - I think we don't need to talk about the threats that could occur if *pure* JavaScript had the possibilities to solve OP's question, no matter the user consent or not (as he was referring to).

---

Anyhow, the solution in this specific case is to use `chrome.tabs.highlight()` and `chrome.windows.update()` from the background script. Credit to *@rails_has_elegance*.

`chrome.tabs.highlight(highlightInfo: object, callback: function)`, click [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-highlight) for documentation.

`chrome.tabs.update(tabId?: number, updateProperties: object, callback: function)`, once again click [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update) for a full insight to the documentation.

---

For **further reading** purposes I highly suggest taking a look at e.g. [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906976/how-to-get-focus-to-a-chrome-tab-which-created-desktop-notification) which deals with a similar problem. **Note**: The first answer of the user *@Mohamd Mansour* is deprecated - the current pendant to the gone `window.focus()` is the mentioned `chrome.tabs.highlight()` which, if you read the description of `chrome.tabs.highlight()`, is also slightly mentioned:

> Highlights the given tabs and **focus**es on the first of group. Will
> appear to do nothing if the specified tab is currently active.

Comment: I hereby award the bounty for this detailed answer, in which you kindly compliment me on my use of the word 'logically'.